# Method Overriding-C# vs java

Tags: java, c#, oop

Is method overriding principle different in Java from C#?I work for c# and now asked to debug a code in java .

Its just to clarify my concept.I have an code that override method in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   public  class A
    {
        public void Food()
        {
            Console.Write("1");

        }


    }

    public class B : A
    {
        public  void Food()
        {
            Console.Write("2");
        }

    }

    public class program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new B();
            a.Food();               

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**-1 (no doubt) (in C#)but when same code I executed in java ,I got out put as  "2".
Just curious to know the reason as overriding principle can be differnt on languages.Sorry I have no experience in java.

Thanks

Comment: You're using an instance of `B` through a variable of `A` but basically you're calling `Food()` on a `B` instance and hence you get 2.

Comment: Compared to C#, methods in Java are automatically `virtual`.

Comment: @KevinEsche,@Thomas - I have no counter words for that and I totally agree but my question was basically "How java have different output" though it is same coding principle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C#, if you want to make a method overridable, you have to use the keyword `virtual` in the superclass. Looking at your example, if you would have added `virtual` to the method `Food` in class `A`, the output would have been `2` instead of `1`:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Food()
    {
        Console.Write("1");
    }
}
```

In Java, there is no `virtual` keyword. Methods are automatically `virtual`. There is no way to make a method non-virtual in Java to get the same behaviour as C#.

Comment: OK.thanks a lot.I did not use virtual intentionally in c# .Well thanks for clarifying my doubt. Java is different from c#

Comment: The last sentence is half right. You *can* make a method non-virtual in Java with the `final` keyword. But then derived classes can't contain a method with the same name. So it's true you cannot create the same behaviour.

Comment: @Dennis_E What you're saying is also half right... if you make a method `final` then subclasses *can* contain a method with the same name, but not with the same name and the same arguments (the same method signature), in other words, you can't override the method but there can still be overloaded versions.

Comment: @Jesper You're right, I should have said signature. It's what I meant, but I wasn't precise.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info, based on your example

`A a = new B()
 a.Food();`

The called `Foo` method is the one inside the `A` class.

What if I changed the type I'm using,

`B a = new B()
 a.Food();`

So in this case, the method called now is the `Foo` method of class `B`.

So not all the time that the method of a super class has a higher precedence, it alo matters on which type you are using to declare an object.

So same as the accepted answer, you need a `virtual` keyword to allow method overriding in C#. It is best practice to also to specify the `override` method in your derived class.

```
public  class A
{
    public virtual void Food()
    {
        Console.Write("1");

    }


}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Food()
    {
        Console.Write("2");
    }

}
```

So what if I have another class that inherits the derived class? (Third level of inheritance)

```
public class C : B
{
    public override void Food()
    {
        Console.Write("2");
    }

}
```

So no need to set `B` as virtual just specify the override keyword in the deepest level.